# Push ViewModel instead of ContentPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I use ViewModels for each of my `ContentPage`. Whenever I want to change pages, I call:

```
App.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyContentPage);
```

But this isn't true MVVM because my ViewModel is directly referencing my view. Is there a way to instead push the ViewModel in Xamarin.Forms? Do I need to use a framework like MvvmCross for this? I want to do something like this:

```
App.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyViewModel);
```

Or even better:

```
App.Navigation.PushAsync<MyViewModel>();
```

Comment: Try looking at Prism for Xamarin Forms. They have great support and lots of videos out there. I have also setup a public GitHub repo with a Prism and validation with dataannotations setup. Please have a look here: https://github.com/1n5an1ty/templates.mobileapp.cross.prism and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if I want real Mvvm I need to use a framework like Prism or MvvmCross

Comment: You don't have to, but it definitely helps with the setup and registration parts of MVVM. It also has some nifty navigation services that might help with what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is also very good at deep linking. If you have plans for that down the road it might make the move even more worth it.